# Whats the proplem with Mysql update query with subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this

```
UPDATE `user_plan_details` 
SET    `plan_expiry_date` = Date_add((SELECT plan_expiry_date 
                                      FROM   `user_plan_details` 
                                      WHERE  user_id = 56 
                                             AND 
                                     user_plan_details.is_current_plan = 1) 
                                   , INTERVAL 30 day) 
WHERE  `user_id` = '56' 
       AND user_plan_details.is_current_plan = 1
```

I got error message like this when executing this query

> MySQL Database Error: You can't specify target table 'user_plan_details' for update in FROM clause

The sub query

```
SELECT DATE_ADD((SELECT plan_expiry_date FROM `user_plan_details` WHERE user_id = 56 AND user_plan_details.is_current_plan = 1 ), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

gives the result

```
1/11/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

Whats problem with my query? please help me.

Comment: If you don't format your code properly, I'm not going to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the last item at [Subquery Errors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/subquery-errors.html) "Incorrectly used table in subquery".

It says you can use subqueries in an update statement, but you cannot use the *same* table in the update *and* subselect.

But you can try this one instead

```
UPDATE `user_plan_details` 
SET    `plan_expiry_date` = Date_add(plan_expiry_date, INTERVAL 30 day) 
WHERE  `user_id` = '56' 
       AND user_plan_details.is_current_plan = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e6ed/1/0) for testing.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is due to you are updating a table whose records you are fetching from a subquery on that table. MYSQL wont allow this, you need to fool the db by creating a temp table on the fly

You can simply ::

```
UPDATE `user_plan_details` 
SET    `plan_expiry_date` = Date_add(plan_expiry_date, INTERVAL 30 day) 
WHERE  `user_id` = '56' 
       AND user_plan_details.is_current_plan = 1
```

or if you want to do it in your style ::
 as ::

```
UPDATE `user_plan_details` 
SET    `plan_expiry_date` = Date_add(
Select temp_itself.plan_expiry_date from 
(SELECT plan_expiry_date 
                                      FROM   `user_plan_details` 
                                      WHERE  user_id = 56 
                                             AND 
                                     user_plan_details.is_current_plan = 1) 
                                   , INTERVAL 30 day) temp_itself
WHERE  `user_id` = '56' 
       AND user_plan_details.is_current_plan = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way:

```
update user_plan_details as t1, (select DATE_ADD((SELECT plan_expiry_date FROM 
   `user_plan_details` WHERE  user_id = 56 AND user_plan_details.is_current_plan = 1 ),
    INTERVAL 30 DAY) as t2 ) as t3  set t1.plan_expiry_date=t3.t2 where t1.`user_id` = 
    '56' AND t1.is_current_plan = 1 ;
```